# tables structure for a publication system

Tags: mysql, database

I have a project to build in-memory database for a publication system and I want a help in the database structure, what will be the structure and fields of the tables and the relations between them.
the following is an explanation for the database and tables
 In this project, the schema consists of 3 tables: Users, Content, License, sufficient columns should be added to support licenses based on time limits (including perpetual) or number of accesses that give access to specific content slices (a content slice is any criteria that can identify a piece of content such as publication date within a range or a list of content ids and/or a filter on Journal name).

I tried to write 3 tables.

user table and consists of:

```
-id
-name
-password
-authority
```

license table:

```
-id
-name
```

user-license table"

```
-id
-user-id (FK)
-license-id (FK)
-price
-expiration date 
-created at
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - as it stands, your question is not one we can answer. What is missing with your initial solution?

Comment: Do several users can have the same license ? Does a user can have several licenses ?

Comment: the users cannot have the same license and the user can have several licenses.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understood your problem is with giving permissions to several uses. Which is java application of this. That's why you have java tag. Because there is nothing wrong with database like that. if so

simply Try to use hibernate

or create a new class with methods specially to read or write data

Then let the user to access those methods as you wish by inheritance or any approach you like

Comment: my problem is how to design the tables and the relations between them, I have already done with 3 tables and don't know how to do the content

Answer (score 0):

my problem is how to design the tables and the relations between them, I have already done with 3 tables and don't know how to do the content

Answer (score 0):

You have a 1-N relationship between users and licenses, where one user can have several licences, and each licence belong to one user only.

To represent such a relationship, two tables should be enough instead of three. You don't need additionnal bridge table `user-license` :

- the `user` table contains one record per user level (id, name, password, ...)
- the `licence` table contains one record per licence, with all relevant information (name, price, expiration, ...) **and** a foreign key that references id of the user to whom the licences belong

Here is how to add the foreign key to table `license` :

```
ALTER TABLE license 
    ADD user_id INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
ALTER TABLE license
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_user_id 
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id);
```

Comment: what about the content, what is the relation and how can I do it?

Comment: @AIMadi : what is the `content` table and what does it contains ? You did put any information about this table in your original post.

Comment: the content is the publication
sufficient columns should be added to support licenses based on time limits (including perpetual) or number of accesses that give access to specific content slices (a content slice is any criteria that can identify a piece of content such as publication date within a range or a list of content ids and/or a filter on Journal name).

Comment: the content is the publication sufficient columns should be added to support the number of accesses that give access to specific content slices (a content slice is any criteria that can identify a piece of content such as publication date within a range or a list of content ids and/or a filter on Journal name).